# Pass a text string value to hiddenbform value field for post

Tags: javascript, html, string, forms

Pass a text string value  to hidden form value field for post...
Here's my code..

```
Onmouseover="goto function();"

Function gotofunction (){ document.getelementbyid 
('icon').src="icon2.png";
Var chosen="mobiles"; document.getelementbyid ('value').value = chosen;
Ondblclick = function () {document.getelementbyid ('send').submit (); 
return false; }

<Form id="send" action="Page.php" target="iframe" method="post">
<input id="choice" type="hidden" type="text" name="genres" value=" "/>
<input type="hidden" type="submit" value="post">
</form>
```

My problem is passing the chosen variable to the value field to send to the php page.... I can hard code it for every blooming icon with static values but it would be sensible to pass a string text veritable to the value.  Iv tried loads of methods from php echo to createattributes but I failed terriblelying. .

If anyone has a workaround to pass a simple string value to the value field you would really be worthy of a thank you.

Comment: How does it even work? You are using uppercase `Var` and `Function`. You should have syntax error in the console.

Comment: Tablet typos not the actual code

Comment: The real code is running a website all be it local host,  but iv got stuck at the sending of a simple string text to the value field of a Form,  been at it all day next night

Comment: Still after formatting the code I don't understand. Try harder and update your question.

Comment: Var chosen ="sometext"

Comment: wow. impressive. try again.

Comment: Sometext going to value field as veriable,

Comment: Lol..... its as simple as it looks, really it is.... send a text string as a veriable, to the value field of a Form for parsing

Comment: So if it's as simple as it looks then why do you have any problem with that?

Comment: If you don't care about the quality of your question then how can you expect people to help you?

Comment: Oh I  care... enough to tolerate the  insensitivity of the comments received as a learner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with JavaScript as it is case sensitive... and you also need to ensure the ids you are using exist (you can test this easily too, but for now let's just make things run...)

```
var target = document.getElementById('mytarget');
target.addEventListener("mouseenter", gotofunction);
target.ondblclick = function () { document.getElementById('send').submit(); }

function gotofunction() {
    document.getElementById('icon').src = "icon2.png";
    var chosen = "mobiles";
    document.getElementById('choice').value = chosen;
}
```

And the HTML...

```
<p id="mytarget">
Target?
</p>
<img id="icon" />
<form id="send" action="Page.php" target="iframe" method="post">
    <input id="choice" type="hidden" type="text" name="genres" value=" "/>
    <input type="hidden" type="submit" value="post">
</form>
```

And if you want the chosen variable to come from PHP... you could do this:

```
var chosen = "<?= $chosen ?>";
```

Or this is even simpler...

```
<input id="choice" type="hidden" type="text" name="genres" value="<?= $chosen ?>" />;
```

In both cases, you'll want to be sure there are no quotes in your string.

Comment: But I tried that way dint work,, page stayed on loader

Comment: .value = chosen

Comment: Tried create element ('value' , chosen) tried <?Php echo  $chosen been through them all, best I got was hard coding value="mywords"

Comment: Wanting mywords to be $chosen

Comment: P's I'm using a tablet sorry for the inconvenience, I'm not at home on pc

Comment: Example of passing the data from PHP added.

Comment: Yes I'm hoping to use the php route for the server side stuff, I'm going to be attempting a searchbar next..should be interesting..

Comment: The problem I'm faceing is getting element VALUE by I'd and passing in the var  into it... iv tried all most everything I visited seen online , other than different workarounds completely.

Comment: var chosen = "<?= $chosen ?>"; seems right, but the  sending it to <input id="choice" type="hidden" type="text" name="genres" VALUE="<?= $chosen ?>" /> from J's function